# Update SMS as read in phone, upon reading an SMS in my app

Tags: android, listview, sms, android-lazyadapter

Hi I am developing an android SMS app where I am fetching the SMS stored in the phone and displaying it on a list view. How can I update a SMS as read in the phone, upon reading an SMS in my app.

I refered the following link,
 [Android: how to mark sms as read in onReceive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637271/android-how-to-mark-sms-as-read-in-onreceive?lq=1)

This did not work. What can i use instead of this.
Please suggest. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> How can I update a SMS as read in the phone, upon reading an SMS in my app.

You can't, reliably. There are hundreds, perhaps thousands, of SMS clients on the Play Store. None of them have to expose some sort of API to allow third parties to somehow mark SMS messages as "read".

Comment: @sanjana: "There are lot of widgets which can do it" -- not reliably. Those app widgets will not necessarily be able to mark messages as read in all SMS client applications. "How have they done?" -- presumably, they followed the unreliable instructions from the question that you linked to and its accepted answer. That should work for those SMS clients that happen to use the undocumented and unsupported SMS `ContentProvider`, at least until Google decides to lock down access to that `ContentProvider`.