# Android4.4 can not handle sms intent with "vnd.android-dir/mms-sms"

Tags: java, android, android-intent, sms, android-4.4-kitkat

My application has a button to start default sms activity and
it worked perfectly fine all android version except new one, Android 4.4(kitkat)
Here is the code:

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
    smsIntent.putExtra("address", member.getPhoneNumber().trim());
    context.startActivity(smsIntent);
}
```

And I get error messages

```
11-08 02:08:32.815: E/AndroidRuntime(14733): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW typ=vnd.android-dir/mms-sms (has extras) }
```

I know that google made some changes on how the default sms app handles sms intents.
but my app is not a sms app but it only has function to start default sms app with recipient number. so please help.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To start the SMS app with number populated use action `ACTION_SENDTO`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:" + Uri.encode(phoneNumber)));
startActivity(intent);
```

This will work on Android 4.4. It should also work on earlier versions of Android however as the APIs were never public the behavior might vary. If you didn't have issues with your prior method I would probably just stick to that pre-4.4 and use `ACTION_SENDTO` for 4.4+.

Comment: thx it works!! but I also try to send message body with the intent and I use intent.putExtra("sms_body", "blahblah"); but this extra doesn't  work and no message body appears on the message activity. so do you have any idea with this too??

Comment: not sure if that's possible anymore. you can certainly populate the body text using ACTION_SEND instead along with the EXTRA_TEXT extra, however that will mean you can't specify the phone number.

Answer (score 0):

to start the sms app without insert the number, you should delete setType

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"));
intent.putExtra("sms_body", "smsMsgVar");
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue happened when you are testing with Emulator,

Please test with the actual device.

Answer (score 0):

**In Kotlin this code works:**

```
val defaultSmsPackageName = Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(activity)  
            val sendIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
            sendIntent.type = "text/plain"
            sendIntent.putExtra("address", "sms:"+contactNumber)
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getString(R.string.share_msg_body))
            Timber.e("defaultSmsPackageName: "+defaultSmsPackageName)
            if (defaultSmsPackageName != null){ //Can be null in case that there is no default, then the user would be able to choose any app that support this intent.
                sendIntent.setPackage(defaultSmsPackageName)
                activity!!.startActivity(sendIntent)
            }
```