# Android sms-intent issues with 4.4.3 update

Tags: android, android-intent, sms

I have an sms app that sends an sms intent to create a message. Previous code from january and march that once used to work now crashes when the startactivity for the intent runs. 
Is anyone familiar with any fixes? I did the code below for an sms-intent and it won't send the intent. It works inside the AVD, but not on my nexus 5.

```
Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "test"); 
smsIntent.putExtra("address", "123123123");
smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms"); 
startActivity(smsIntent);
```

It used to work before on all previous versions on my phone. Now they don't.

Comment: Would you post logcat from the device?

Comment: Relates to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19853220/android4-4-can-not-handle-sms-intent-with-vnd-android-dir-mms-sms ?

Comment: From the AVD or the real phone? I downloaded aLogcat for my device, and it doesnt show anything new in logcat for my real phone when I run the application.