# change read status of sms in android

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I build an android SMS app and i want to received sms from my smsReceiver everything is going to fine i used the flowing code for on conversation activity and this method perfectly worked but when I go back my default SMS App is marked the messages unread and it show notification on icon as unread I don't how  i changed the status of default message app to read status true I am using huawei G610 for testing and API 17 jelly beans

```
public static void markMessageRead(Context context, String number, String body) {

    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    try {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            String address =(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address")));
            int read = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("read"));
            if (address.equals(number) &&  read== 0) {
                if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body")).startsWith(body)) {
                    String SmsMessageId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put("read", 1);
                    int iii =context.getContentResolver().update(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), values, "_id=" + SmsMessageId, null);
                    Log.i("update", iii+"");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
      } catch(Exception e) {
          Log.e("Mark Read", "Error in Read: "+e.toString());
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**May This Help You**

```
    private void markMessageRead(Context context, String number, String body) {

            Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
            Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
            try{

            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    if ((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address")).equals(number)) && (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("read")) == 0)) {
                        if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body")).startsWith(body)) {
                            String SmsMessageId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
                            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                            values.put("read", true);
                            context.getContentResolver().update(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), values, "_id=" + SmsMessageId, null);
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
      }catch(Exception e)
      {
          Log.e("Mark Read", "Error in Read: "+e.toString());
      }
}
```

Comment: I thinks that is the same method i used above and change value of read as 1 or as true

Comment: Yes Reference From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637271/android-how-to-mark-sms-as-read-in-onreceive

Comment: If You search related question then you defiantly get the answer

Comment: my dear its perfectly work  and status updated successfully but when i see default messaging app is show that received message is not read and its still unread

Answer (score 1):

This would probably make it all right:

```
context.getContentResolver().update(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), values, "_id = ?", new String[]{SmsMessageId}); //code
```