# Change the read state of sms in android

Tags: android, sms, telephony

I am developing a clone of sms application which is in built of the android devices. For reading status updating used the resource regarding the below link.

But it is not working. Any can give me a effective solution on this issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22470201/change-read-status-of-sms-in-android
Used to resolve this issue, but not working correctly