# How to update list item in listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have an `ListView` with a `SmsArrayAdapter` of SMSItem objects.

**SmsArrayAdapter.java**

```
public class SmsArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SMSItem>
```

I want to update item of `ListView`. That is why I am taking SMSItem objects in `onItemClick` method and trying to mark them as read.

```
SMSItem smsMessageStr = (SMSItem) arrayAdapter.getItem(pos);

if (smsMessageStr.status == false) {
    ((SmsArrayAdapter) arrayAdapter).setRead(pos, smsMessageStr.ID); 

    Toast.makeText(this, "ID is " + smsMessageStr.ID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

The method for marking sms as read as follows which is declared in **SmsArrayAdapter.java**

```
public void setRead(int position, String smsMessageId) {
        smsBody.get(position).status = true;
        SMSItem smsItem = smsBody.get(position);
        smsItem.status = true;
        smsBody.set(position, smsItem);
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("read", true);
        int flag = context.getContentResolver().update(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"),
            values, "_id=" + smsMessageId, null);
    Toast.makeText(context, "The result is "+flag, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

The sms is not marking as read. Where is the problem ?

Comment: Is there an error that you're getting? Does `"read"` need to pass `1` instead of `true`?

Comment: I am getting no error .

Comment: Try to correct condition this way if (!smsMessageStr.status) { instead of if (smsMessageStr.status == false) {, boolean value not required == comparison.

Comment: If sms is unread the status of the sms is false . \

Comment: you have to call notifydatasetchanged after changing the smsitem object

Comment: @AdityaChauhan,Look at code man his already do it.

Comment: @osimerpothe what is the return result of `context.getContentResolver().update(...)`?

Comment: The return result is 0

Comment: It means the row is not updated,

Comment: What do you want mean by content provider ? I have not used content provider in anywhere .

Comment: Check out this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637271/android-how-to-mark-sms-as-read-in-onreceive

Comment: I have checked this .

Comment: The return result of update query is 0 . What is the solution behind this ?