# The return value of update query is 0

Tags: android, sms

I want to marks a sms as read . I have id of that sms . I have tried the following code to mark this sms as read .

```
public void setRead(int position, String smsMessageId) {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("read",true);
        int flag = context.getContentResolver().update(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"),
                values, "_id=" + smsMessageId, null);
        Toast.makeText(context, "The result is "+flag, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
}
```

But the return result is 0 . Why is the return result  0 ?

Comment: in which os version are you trying?

Comment: I am trying in Android 4.4.2

Comment: Did you validate that you are actually targeting the right messageId?

Comment: Yes . I am actually targeting the right messageID .

Comment: Do the logs say that the update is occuring fine or being denied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My app is not set as default . That is why , the return result is 0 .If the app is set as default , then the return result is 1 .